# PHP fopen() can't create or update log file (ubuntu)

Tags: php, fopen, file-get-contents, fwrite, file-exists

I give chmod 777 to logs folder but it doesn't work ... I have to create log file day by day . It doesn't create file ... Why ?

```
<?php
$server = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$today = date("d-m-Y");
$timest = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
$file = "logs/" . $today . ".txt";
$succ = $_SESSION['logged'];

if (file_exists($file))
    {
    $add = file_get_contents($file);
    $add . = "\nServer : " . $server . "\t Username : " . $username . "\t Timestamp : " . $timest . "\t Success : " . $succ;
    file_put_contents($file, $add);
    }
  else
    {
    $fc = fopen($file, "w") or die("Unable to open file");
    $txt = "\nServer : " . $server . "\t Username : " . $username . "\t Timestamp : " . $timest . "\t Success : " . $succ;
    fwrite($fc, $txt);
    fclose($fc);
    }

?>
```

Comment: can't create file on ubuntu server

Comment: can remove $file = "logs/".$today.".txt"; 
and make a simple file name  for test $file = "test.txt"; and try .